# jQuery mobile: Listview with rounded corners using CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to style a `jQuery` mobile listview using `CSS` and give them a **border radius**.

This sort of works fine but the issue is that the first `<li></li>` and the last `<li></li>` have only 2 corners rounded!

To demonstrate the issue please look at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qw8th8k7/)

This is the simple `CSS`:

```
.dotted-list li a{

border-radius:5px;
margin:5px !important;
}
    .dotted-list{
        background-color:#CCC !important;
        /*margin-left:-8px !important;
        margin-right:16px !important;
        padding-left:5px !important;
        padding-right:15px !important;*/
        margin:0 !important;
        width:100%;


        }
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is overwritten by: `.ui-listview > li > a.ui-btn` in the jquery.min.css file. Add `!important` to the `border-radius: 5px` and it will work.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qw8th8k7/1/).